# SVN update not working after SVN relocate

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, relocation

I have recently migrated my SVN repository from SERVER1 to SERVER2.

- installed SVN on SERVER2.
- used `svnrdump` utility to dump the repository.
- used `svndump load` utility to load the dump file to new svn server.

I checked out a working  copy **WC** from path `http://SERVER1/project1/data` from SERVER1 svn.

Note one thing here:

- When I took dump, SVN revision on SERVER1 was 12345.
- When I checked out **WC** , SVN revision was 13456.

Now, using `relocate from tortoise svn on windows`, I have **relocated WC** to SERVER2 svn to path `http://SERVER2/project1/data`.

Relocation is successfull.

After this, I am trying to `check-in` changes which were made from rev-12345 till rev-13456 to  `http://SERVER2/project1/data`.

But, here is what is happening:

- Commit operation does not show any files to be committed.
- Check for modification does not show any changes.
- SVN Update shows error 'No Such Revision: 13456'.
- I changed a file which existed on **WC** and on `http://SERVER2/project1/data` as well, and tried to commit it. Here also it gives 'No Such Revision: 13456'.

I was expecting that when **WC** at rev-13456 from SERVER1 will be relocated to  `http://SERVER2/project1/data` at rev-12345 from SERVER2, it will show all the differences which were made between these two revisions.

*NOTE: I am trying above because SERVER1 will be shutdown in some time. As of now, both repositories exist. SERVER1 is still being used by people and SERVER2 is to be kept up-to-date with SERVER1.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you checked out your working copy at a later revision than what exists on the server you relocated to, it has no reference point to calculate changes.  This method of updating SERVER2 will not work.  You have two options:

1. To properly update SERVER2 with all revisions that are missing, you must do a partial dump/load of the remaining revisions.  `svnadmin dump repo_path -r 12346 --incremental`, then load on new server.  It will dump only revisions for 12346 forward.  This will only work if you have not added other revisions to SERVER2 that were not part of SERVER1.
2. If you don't care about the intervening revision history and just want to dump all the changes in that time into the new server as 1 revision, do a fresh check out from the new server first.  Then copy all changes over from your WC from SERVER1 into this WC of SERVER2 and commit.

The first option is better and probably even less work depending on how complicated the changes are.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Can you please elaborate on 'it has no reference point to calculate changes'.

Comment: Sure, when you check out a working copy from subversion, it remembers what revision number it is currently at.  That way, when you do an SVN Update it goes out to the server and says give me all the changes from my current revision to the HEAD.

You checked out a WC from a server with version 13456 then relocated to one that did not have that version number, so anytime you try to do something that involves getting changes or applying changes to that revision, it can't do it becuase the revision doesn't exist on the new server.